# Green screen when playing video in media player classic

Tags: video, media-player-classic

when I open any video in MPC-HC it shows a green screen, audio and subtitles still work but no image, any help is appreciated. 
I'm running windows 7 32-bit and MPC-HC version 1.7.1

Answer (score 1):

A green screen in Media Player Classic means it can't display the videofeed. This is often due to a codec being used that you do not currently have installed. If you use a codec pack such as K-Lite Mega Codec Pack, be sure to update it once in a while because at some point it just gets outdated.

To fix the issue, find out what codec was used and install that specific codec (or if you are lazy, just install the latest K-Lite Mega codec pack).